# Alert Message in case of error or successful submission of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

So I've this form on which I'm trying to apply simple form validation and everything is working fine except I want to display an alert message if a user leaves the empty field or if a form has successfully submitted.
But the problem is I am having this purple line below my form which I want to hide before the form submission.

```js
/*simple form validation script*/
var formData = document.forms.myForm;
var show = document.getElementById("alert");

formData.onsubmit = function() {

  if (formData.name.value == "") {
    show.innerHTML = "Please fill out all fields!";
    return false;
  } else {
    $("#alert").css("display", "block");
    show.innerHTML = "successful submission of form!";
    return true;
  }
};
```

```css
#alert {
  margin: 30px auto;
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: background 2s ease;
  -moz-transition: background 2s ease;
  -ms-transition: background 2s ease;
  -o-transition: background 2s ease;
  transition: background 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<!--simple form validation with javascript example-->
<form name="myForm" action="#">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  <!--alert-->
  <div id="alert"></div>
</form>

<script src="formValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please help me or at least clear this logic.
Thank you!

Comment: Why are you mixing up both jQuery and JavaScript. Use one, it is easier.

Comment: Set `#alert` to `display:none;` by default

Comment: submitting form reloads page.

Comment: Then I ain't going to see this message by doing that @JacobGray

Comment: as of what i understood you want to hide the alert div when form loads for first time...so you have to set its display property default to hide(display:none) and that should solve the problem....and in validation show it in both cases..

Comment: in your case you can use preventDefault() to avoid default form submit behavior as you are submitting the form to itself on successful form submit it causing the form reload and result is you are not getting success message..

Comment: @AishaSalman that's why you show it with JS

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this code you have is, you are submitting it **normally**, which means, the page gets **navigated to another page**, where you see the POST results. Here, the new page is loaded and all your old JavaScript is discarded.

For showing an `#alert` with CSS, you **need to be** in the **same page**, so using AJAX is the best way. This is the reason, you aren't seeing the output, while it navigates to a new page, even before the JavaScript executes.

Also adding the below code at the top, will help you hiding the alert box (which now displays as a thin line) before it gets displayed:

```
$("#alert").hide();
```

> **Note:** Why are you mixing up both jQuery and JavaScript. Use one, it is easier.

**Update:** Hiding the purple thin line code:

```js
/*simple form validation script*/
$(function () {
  $("#alert").hide();
  $("form").submit(function() {
    if (this.name.value == "") {
      $("#alert").text("Please fill out all fields!").show();
    } else {
      $("#alert").text("Successful submission of form!").show();
      $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function () {
        $("#alert").text("Successful submission of form!").show();
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
#alert {
  margin: 30px auto;
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: background 2s ease;
  -moz-transition: background 2s ease;
  -ms-transition: background 2s ease;
  -o-transition: background 2s ease;
  transition: background 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--simple form validation with javascript example-->
<form name="myForm" action="#">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  <!--alert-->
  <div id="alert"></div>
</form>

<script src="formValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope this clears.

Comment: Yes thanks for the clarification but I want to hide that purple thin line before it gets displayed @PraveenKumar

Comment: @AishaSalman Yes, you need to use `$("#alert").hide();` on the top.

Comment: Yes I have set it to the top but it's not working here @PraveenKumar

Comment: Yes got it now but then clicking on submit button it is not letting me seeing the message @PraveenKumar

Comment: @AishaSalman I gave the explanation for that at first to use the AJAX code.

Comment: @AishaSalman You need to use AJAX for showing the message buddy. Do you need code for displaying AJAX then?

Answer (score 2):

Set #alert to display:none; by default

```
    #alert {
      display:none;
    }
```

JS:

```
show.style.display="block";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try removing border attribute from this code:

  #alert {
  margin: 30px auto;
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: background 2s ease;
  -moz-transition: background 2s ease;
  -ms-transition: background 2s ease;
  -o-transition: background 2s ease;
  transition: background 2s ease;
}
```

You can try giving border using .css property in js as below:

```
$("#alert").css('border','1px solid transparent');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code. I have tested it, its working..
`<style>
      #alert {
      margin: 30px auto;
      background: purple;
      color: #fff; 
      padding: 0px 20px;
      width: 30%;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      -webkit-transition: background 2s ease;
      -moz-transition: background 2s ease;
      -ms-transition: background 2s ease;
      -o-transition: background 2s ease;
      transition: background 2s ease;
     }
    </style>`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!--simple form validation with javascript example-->
       <form name="myForm" action="#">
       <label>Name:</label>
       <input type="text" name="name">
       <label>Password:</label>
       <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
       <!--alert-->
       <div id="alert"></div>
     </form> 
    <!-- end snippet -->`

`<script>
     /*simple form validation script*/
    $(function () {
      $("#alert").hide();
      $("form").submit(function() {
        if (this.name.value == "") {
          $("#alert").text("Please fill out all fields!").show();
        } else {
          $("#alert").text("Successful submission of form!").show();
          $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function () {
            $("#alert").text("Successful submission of form!").show();
          });
        }
        return false;
      });
    });

  $("#alert").css('border','1px solid transparent');
</script>`